# rm -f <file> command returns "invalid Argument" mv, chmod met with same output

Tags: command-line, freebsd

Below I've included a truss of the command, I've tried various ways to rm, but each one is met with the same output: 
NOTE: this was run on an isilon NAS cluster (their Technical support is also stumped.)

````
Cluster-1# rm -f "478.ts"
rm: 478.ts: Invalid argument

Cluster-1# truss -a rm 478.ts
mmap(0x0,32768,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366148608 (0x80061d000)
issetugid(0x80081da80,0x7fffffffefd8,0x40,0x0,0xffff80080081eaa8,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/etc",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=93955,size=3072,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/etc/libmap.conf",{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=102839,size=47,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
open("/etc/libmap.conf",O_CLOEXEC,01760)         = 3 (0x3)
fstat(3,{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=102839,size=47,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,47,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,3,0x0)         = 34366181376 (0x800625000)
close(3)                                         = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/usr",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=23492,size=512,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/usr/local",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=23507,size=512,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/usr/local/etc",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=23846,size=1024,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/usr/local/etc/libmap.d",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=24971,size=512,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
open("/usr/local/etc/libmap.d",O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC,0165) = 3 (0x3)
__sysctl(0x7fffffffc0d8,0x2,0x80081e6bc,0x7fffffffc0d0,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
fstatfs(0x3,0x7fffffffc118,0x80081e6bc,0x7fffffffc0d0,0x0,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,36864,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366185472 (0x800626000)
getdirentries(0x3,0x800623000,0x1000,0x800622028,0x0,0x0) = 80 (0x50)
lstat("/usr",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=23492,size=512,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/usr/local",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=23507,size=512,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/usr/local/etc",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=23846,size=1024,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/usr/local/etc/libmap.d",{ mode=drwxr-xr-x ,inode=24971,size=512,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
lstat("/usr/local/etc/libmap.d/mft.conf",{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=25013,size=50,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
open("/usr/local/etc/libmap.d/mft.conf",O_CLOEXEC,0165) = 4 (0x4)
fstat(4,{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=25013,size=50,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,50,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,4,0x0)         = 34366222336 (0x80062f000)
close(4)                                         = 0 (0x0)
munmap(0x80062f000,50)                           = 0 (0x0)
getdirentries(0x3,0x800623000,0x1000,0x800622028,0x50,0x8080808080808080) = 0 (0x0)
close(3)                                         = 0 (0x0)
munmap(0x800625000,47)                           = 0 (0x0)
open("/var/run/ld-elf.so.hints",O_CLOEXEC,0162)  = 3 (0x3)
read(3,"Ehnt\^A\0\0\0\M^@\0\0\0m\0\0\0\0"...,128) = 128 (0x80)
lseek(3,0x80,SEEK_SET)                           = 128 (0x80)
read(3,"/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/compat:/u"...,109) = 109 (0x6d)
close(3)                                         = 0 (0x0)
access("/lib/libc.so.7",0)                       = 0 (0x0)
open("/lib/libc.so.7",O_CLOEXEC,030503770)       = 3 (0x3)
fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=103356,size=1721078,blksize=16384 }) = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34366181376 (0x800625000)
mmap(0x0,3821568,PROT_NONE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_NOCORE,-1,0x0) = 34368253952 (0x80081f000)
mmap(0x80081f000,1507328,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34368253952 (0x80081f000)
mmap(0x800b8e000,49152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x16f000) = 34371854336 (0x800b8e000)
mmap(0x800b9a000,172032,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34371903488 (0x800b9a000)
munmap(0x800625000,4096)                         = 0 (0x0)
close(3)                                         = 0 (0x0)
munmap(0x800629000,24576)                        = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,102400,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366197760 (0x800629000)
sysarch(0x81,0x7fffffffd0a8,0x4,0x0,0xffffffffffaac5e0,0xf0000000) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)                 = 0 (0x0)
readlink("/etc/malloc.conf",0x7fffffffc7d0,1024) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
issetugid(0x80096477e,0x7fffffffc7d0,0xffffffffffffff00,0x2,0x40,0xffffffff0fffffff) = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,262144,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366300160 (0x800642000)
munmap(0x800642000,262144)                       = 0 (0x0)
mmap(0x0,520192,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366300160 (0x800642000)
munmap(0x800642000,253952)                       = 0 (0x0)
munmap(0x8006c0000,4096)                         = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)                 = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)                 = 0 (0x0)
geteuid()                                        = 0 (0x0)
sigaction(SIGINFO,{ 0x402280 SA_RESTART ss_t },{ SIG_DFL SA_RESTART ss_t }) = 0 (0x0)
ioctl(0,TIOCGETA,0xffffd970)                     = 0 (0x0)
lstat("478.ts",{ mode=-rwxrwxrwx ,inode=57420697287,size=0,blksize=8192 }) = 0 (0x0)
access("478.ts",2)                               = 0 (0x0)
unlink("478.ts")                                 ERR#22 'Invalid argument'
rm: write(2,"rm: ",4)                            = 4 (0x4)
478.tswrite(2,"478.ts",6)                                = 6 (0x6)
: write(2,": ",2)                                        = 2 (0x2)
mmap(0x0,262144,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34366816256 (0x8006c0000)
stat("/usr/share/nls/C/libc.cat",0x7fffffffd290) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
stat("/usr/share/nls/libc/C",0x7fffffffd290)     ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
stat("/usr/local/share/nls/C/libc.cat",0x7fffffffd290) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
stat("/usr/local/share/nls/libc/C",0x7fffffffd290) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
madvise(0x8006c1000,0x1000,0x5,0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab,0x8006c0030,0x800bc2c40) = 0 (0x0)
madvise(0x8006c2000,0x1000,0x5,0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab,0x7fffffffc790,0x800bc2c40) = 0 (0x0)
Invalid argument
write(2,"Invalid argument\n",17)                 = 17 (0x11)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)                 = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)                 = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x0) = 0 (0x0)
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)                 = 0 (0x0)
process exit, rval = 1
Cluster-1#```
````

Answer (score 0):

The "Invalid argument" is likely coming from `perror`, [reporting an errno of EINVAL](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/1d6e4247415d264485ee94b59fdbc12e0c566fd0/lib/libc/gen/errlst.c#L64) set by `unlink`.

According to the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unlink&sektion=2), EINVAL can only occur with `unlinkat`, not for `unlink`, and the truss output shows an `unlink` call, so the situation seems impossible. Yet here we are.

I've found some [other reports](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/cant-delete-file-with-strange-name.14612/) of utilities reporting 'Invalid argument' when the underlying filesystem couldn't handle the filename's encoding.

That's probably not the issue for you, since your filename seems to just be simple ASCII characters, but I would suspect that here too EINVAL is being set by filesystem-specific code being invoked by the `unlink` syscall, so this would depend what filesystem you're using.
On an Isilon NAS cluster, that's probably [OneFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneFS_distributed_file_system), unless it's in a strange location (like tmpfs, or a FUSE mount), or on removable media.

If that's the case, you'll probably need to get an actual engineer at Isilon to dig into the code to find out what could cause an EINVAL on unlink.

Comment: ah my apologies it is FreeBSD.

Comment: Can you tell us what filesystem the file is on?

Comment: The only thing they tell me about OneFS FS, is that the File System is a parallel distributed networked file system loosely based on FreeBSD. The actual storage allocation method uses a reed-solomon raid algorithm for files over 128k, for smaller than 128k they are mirrored between cluster nodes. Other than that mess of info it is pretty proprietary.

Comment: And the file is actually on the OneFS filesystem, not in a tmpfs or procfs or FUSE or a USB key or something?

Comment: Yes Sir, it...or I should say they reside only on isilon. written there by an application, but I've not been given the exact write command the app uses. I say they because there are thousands of them.